# Date formatting in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a variable which contain value "20140720". I need to change it to the  format "20/07".

My code is shown below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $date = '20140720';

my $date_format = Time::Piece->strptime($date, '%d/%m');
my $new_date = $date_format->strftime('%d/%m');
print $new_date;
```

I get following error during execution.

> Error parsing time at /usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Time/Piece.pm line 470.

Answer (score 5):

In this line — `Time::Piece->strptime($date, '%d/%m');` — you specified the format that `$date` is **currently in** incorrectly. The second argument describes how the string should be parsed, not the format you want it to be in (which is what the following line is for).

Use `'%Y%m%d'` instead.

Answer (score 3):

With a fixed string, you should use the [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#pack-TEMPLATE%2CLIST)/[`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#unpack-TEMPLATE%2CEXPR) function:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $date = '20140720';

my (undef, $m, $d) = unpack 'A4A2A2', $date;

print "$d/$m";
```

Comment: With a date/time string you should use a date/time parser :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need further date processing, using a simple regular expression may be simpler:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $date = '20140720';
my $new_date = $date;
$new_date =~ s!\d{4}(\d{2})(\d{2})$!$2/$1!;

print $new_date, "\n";
```

Comment: Maybe. But I doubt it :-)